# How can I quickly filter by edited photos on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

Often I will have many versions of a similar photo.  I will select my favorite and then crop and edit this version. Later I would like to  quickly find the nicely edited version from the other photos.  Sometimes I do not want (or forget) to favorite the edited photo after I edit it.  In addition, sometimes I would like to find a photo I edited months or even years ago.  Is there a way to quickly find edited photos in iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a feature for filtering photos in the iOS Photos app which allows you to quickly find previously edited photos.  To access this capability click the three dots at the top right of the photos app (the three dots are located next to the "select" button).

After pressing the three dots (...) you will see the following screen:

[image: Photo Filters in iOS]

Select "Filter" and the screen below will appear.  On this screen select "edited"

[image: Edited Photo Filter iOS]

Finally select "Done" and you will see only your edited photos.

You can reverse this by selecting the three dots again, selecting "Change Filter" and then setting the filter to "All Items"